# 'physical betterment' in the context of 'physical health'

Tags: word-choice, expressions

When the topic and context is health and treatment, would the expression **physical betterment** be broadly understood as one or any combination of the below?

1) betterment of one's health condition
2) one's health improving
3) remission of disease

?

Comment: *Physical betterment* is a phrase I can't see being used in this context in the first place (or any context, really).

Comment: @JasonBassford - are there other expressions that you would suggest? I don't want to use the words healing, cure, and remission.

Comment: It's pretty impossible to say with a sentence for context. *Physical conditioning* would be more natural. Or even just *getting into shape* (but that may not fit into a particular sentence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to refer to the improvement of one's physical health.  Most likely this is one's general health (cardio, bowel) rather than the cure of a particular disease. It would probably be used in contrast to "Psychological betterment".

> Improvements in mental health in response to physical betterment.

A headline like this would probably be about improving mental conditions like anxiety or depression by going to the gym regularly and eating more vegetables.